# Is there an API to get e-mail smtp information (for GMail)

Tags: google-api, smtp, gmail-api, google-admin-sdk

I want to send an e-mail using gmail API.

I want to know if the email was received successfully. And if not, what the problem. (Such as SMTP Log)

I can use Google Admin G-Suite if need.

How can I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `Request read receipt` after an email is sent.  This would notify the sender when the recipient reads the email.

This is not something that is currently available in the gmail api.   you may want to consider submitting a feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/bookmark-groups/78025)

Comment: How do you define an email as having been received?  That it hit their mail server?  That they downloaded the email but didn't open it? You cant see either of those even without the gmail api.    What you want to do is not possible.